# How Can Email constants be added in a table or used securely in a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app, I wish to add all the constants including email constants of my app in a table and access them from there.
 Can we do it? Is it a good approach to do it?
or are there any better alternatives available rather than having credentials plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if i am wrong the reason your asking this question is :

Case 1:

You don't want your password to be plainly visible in your config file.

Case 2 :

Your code could be in public domain and you don't want your API keys and passwords to be visible.

Case 3:

In production environment your config.py shouldn't be vulnerable as it stores passwords as plain text.

In Case 1:
you could store credentials in environment variables
`

```
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

`

In Case 2:

You could use the concept of [Instance folder](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html) in Flask

In which you would have a private instance of config.py which you need not to add in version control

```
config.py
requirements.txt
run.py
instance/
  config.py
yourapp/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  views.py
  templates/
  static/
```

Using Instance on config.py

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

Please refer [this](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html) it will give an in depth understanding.

In Case 3: referring to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/33vkip/afhow_do_i_keep_my_email_server_credentials/)

A good solution for a production server is to host a mail agent such as sendmail or postfix, or else use a third party email service. If you host a mail agent on the same host as your Flask app, you can configure it to not require authentication when the client is from localhost, which removes the requirement of storing credentials in config files or environment.

### Hope it helps you

#### peace